# PHP mailer change variable based on variable from dropdown menu

Tags: php

I am working on a mailer and form. In my form I have a dropdown menu that is populated from a database. The table in the database has 3 columns: id, facility, and email. I need the mailer side to look at the facility and change $mailto to the corresponding email address from the database. I am really new and this has had me stumped for two days.

Dropdown from **form.php**:

```
$queryData = "SELECT * FROM facilities";
$result = mysql_query($queryData);
?>

<select id="cust_Facility" name="cust_Facility">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ?>
        <option value=<?php echo($row['id']); ?>><?php echo($row['facility']); ?></option>
        <?php
    }
?>
        </select>
<?php
?>
```

**Form:**

```
$emailSubject = 'Toner Request';
$mailto = '';
$email = 'Toner Sending Service';


$facilityField = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cust_Facility']);

$queryEmail = "SELECT * FROM facilities WHERE ";
$result = mysql_query($queryEmail);


if (isset($facilityField)) {
        echo "Facility is set";
        }
$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Customer Information<br>
<br>
Facility: $facilityField <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n"; // This takes the email and displays it as who this email is from.
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; // This tells the server to turn the coding into the text.
$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers); // This tells the server what to send.

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Success!</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

When I hit submit on my form it echoes $facilityField as expected. I don't know what to add after that to make it change $mailto based on what value is in $facilityField. When I set $mailto manually I receive the email as expected.

New mail:

```
<?php

include('db.inc');


$emailSubject = 'Toner Request';
$mailto = '';
$email = 'Toner Sending Service';


$facilityField = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cust_Facility']);


$queryEmail = "SELECT email FROM facilities WHERE facility = '".$facilityField."'";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryEmail);

echo "$result\n";

if (isset($facilityField)) {
        echo "Facility is set";
        }


$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Facility: $facilityField <br>
EOD;



$headers = "From: $email\r\n"; // This takes the email and displays it as who this email is from.
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; // This tells the server to turn the coding into the text.
//$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers); // This tells the server what  to send.

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Success!</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

I made the changes above according to my understand of Pogrindis' comment. It doesn't echo $result. It just gives me the echo "Facility is set" and "Success!". What am I still missing?

The final working code:

```
$queryEmail = "SELECT email FROM facilities WHERE facility = '$facilityField'";
$result = mysql_query($queryEmail);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$mailto = $result['email'];
```

Comment: Well what is the output ?

Comment: When I set $mailto manually I receive the email so I know everything works with a static address. When I click submit on my form it echos $facilityField as expected. I just don't know what to do next to make it change $mailto.

Comment: Do you mean you want this? `if (isset($facilityField)) {
        $mailto = $facilityField;
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body is not in a a string. You should be getting an error.

Your $body var should be something llike :

```
$body = "<<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Customer Information<br>
<br>
Facility:". $facilityField ."<br>
EOD";
```

Then you will be able to use it in your mail function.

At the moment however if the facilty is not set it is still trying to send the email. So an undefined error will occur.

Cleaning if your If statement should help with this.

```
if (isset($facilityField)) {
    echo "Facility is set";
     $body = "<<<EOD
     <br><hr><br>
Customer Information<br>
<br>
Facility:". $facilityField ."<br>
EOD";

$headers = "From: $email\r\n"; // This takes the email and displays it as who this email is from.
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; // This tells the server to turn the coding into the text.
$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers); // This tells the server what to send.
            }
else
echo "Please set facility. "
?>
```

Something a bit more verbose as to what is going on would be helpful also.

Also your $mailto; at the top of the page is not defined.

If you have it on the form you should have an email input (to send to this email.) Or if it to you like a contact page it should be set.

```
if(isset($_POST['emailFormName']))
   $mailto = $_POST['emailFormName'];
```

The mailto is now set from the form input called emailFormName.

As your update asked how to populate the mailto based on the facility.

You should be using

```
$mailto = $_POST['cust_Facility'];
```

Comment: The script works when I set $mailto manually. I want $mailto to come from the database where it matches the value of $facilityField.

Comment: Ok your mailto is not set, i have updated my answer to explain where you're going wrong. (As far as you have mentioned anyway! :))

Comment: I need the email address to come from the database not from the form. It needs to be decided based on what is selected and stored in $facilityField. Each facility has an email associated with it in the database.

Comment: So you need to pull it out of your database then.. Do a sql query to pull out the mail. "SELECT email WHERE facility_id=".$facility_id:

Comment: I got it working. The query you suggested, Pogrindis, set me in the right direction. 3 hours of googling later I have a working script. Thank you.